Notepad++ change color of text when you type an open quote but haven't typed the closed quote yet
I'm using Notepad++ 8.6.5 (64-bit) for Windows, editing a ".bas" file (which is configured using the style for "FreeBasic"), and am finding that when typing something within quotes, when I type the open quote, the text color turns this light yellow, which is impossible to see against the white background, and only becomes its normal visible color when I type the closed quote. It's an annoyance I'd like to fix.
I expect Notepad++ has a setting to change this, and I've looked under Settings > Style Configurator, Settings > Preferences, etc., but I'm not seeing where the color is defined for text that comes after a quote that is missing a closed quote.
If anyone knows and would share that info, it would be most appreciated...
